# build a protocol stack for VANET

Tags: openstreetmap, omnet++, veins, sumo

I want to use OMNet++, VEINS, SUMO, or OpenStreetmap where I can have the protocol stack for VANETs, the interchange of messages, the mobility patterns through a real map. Anyone can recommend me which simulator can use please?

Answer (score 1):

You need essentially all of them. OMNet++ does the communication network simulation, SUMO the (vehicular) traffic. Veins couples them both and OSM delivers the street network to SUMO.